# Wifi not being detected on VMWare for Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, wireless, vmware-workstation

I have Ubuntu 14.04 on my VMware workstation 11. I run it on Windows 8. A few days before my internet connection was working on Ubuntu but now when I tried it again the wifi connection is not being detected. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Check your VMWare guest network settings. This is done from the VMWare application preference menu - not from within the Guest machine. 
Make sure it is either in NAT or Bridge mode with the host machine's network card.